# Wordpress htaccess merging with old site files

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a new wordpress site and an old site which has several thousand site files. What my aim is, is to have wordpress manage new pages, then older pages which a user has a link for will load up from the old site instead of wordpress.

Here's what I have so far, which looks correct but doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite%{REQUEST_URI} -f

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If somebody loads example.com/oldpage.htm, it should look for/load the file {document_root}/oldsite/oldpage.htm, if that file doesn't exist, it should continue to the wordpress index.php as normal.

In extension, there might be multiple folders within the oldsite, so it would need to account for example.com/category1/subcat/oldpage.htm too. From my understanding, {REQUEST_URI} should still allow this to happen, its just not working.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!